# Bind WPF ComboBox with choices defined in datatable

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to do something similar to [Data bound WPF ComboBox with choices defined in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917996/data-bound-wpf-combobox-with-choices-defined-in-xaml) but I want to specify the choices in a data table SettingValues instead. This data table will contain three columns: SettingType (int), SettingId (int) and Description. I want to show the description for all rows of a certain SettingType (for example 1) in the combobox. This SettingType I want to be hard coded for each setting. The chosen SettingId I then want to save in another table with a column Setting1.

This question also seems to do something similar: [how to bind ComboBox with DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749842/how-to-bind-combobox-with-datatable).

A first attempt (code snippet):

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Setting1}" SelectedValuePath="SettingId">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>                                 
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

How do I specify the table to use? Now are only the columns specified. How to specify using only certain rows, those whose SettingType match a certain int?

Comment: The first problem solved, part 2 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976358/using-wpf-combobox-to-select-item-from-one-datatable-and-save-to-another-datatab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem of reading values from a data table by using

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbSetting1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ValueDescription}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In the .cs-file the DataContext is set to the rows with SettingType == 1 by using

```
var dataRows1 = svds.SettingValues.Select("SettingType = 1");
cbSetting1.ItemsSource = dataRows1.AsEnumerable();
```

where svds is a DataSet.

Saving the selected setting between sessions is done by using cbSetting1.SelectedItem, to set and get values.